# Efficient Join in hive without OR condition

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to join geographical region table to user's table in `Hive`.
geographical region can be country, state or city level. 
When geographical region is county level, I need to select all the listings in that county so on. My version of hive does not allow OR in join condition.

What is the most efficient way to write this query?

For example,

Region table

```
region_id , city, state, country
1,  Rome, NULL , IT
2, NULL, NULL, BM
3, VANCOUVER, BC, CA
```

User table

```
user_id, city , state, country
103 , VANCOUVER , BC , CA
105 , HAMILTON, NULL, BM
106 , NULL, NULL, BM
```

Result table

```
region_id, user_id, city, state, country
3, 103 , VANCOUVER , BC , CA
2, 105 , HAMILTON, NULL, BM
2, 106 , NULL, NULL, BM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it may not be as efficient as you would like, but this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    coalesce(cty.region_id, sta.region_id, cou.region_id) as region_id, u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN regions cty ON u.city = cty.city
LEFT JOIN regions sta ON u.state = sta.state
LEFT JOIN regions cou ON u.ccountyity = cou.county
```

and alternative would be:

```
SELECT
    r.region_id
  , u.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            regions.region_id, users.user_id
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN regions ON users.city = regions.city
        UNION
        SELECT
            regions.region_id, users.user_id
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN regions ON usesr.state = regions.state
        UNION
        SELECT
            regions.region_id, users.user_id
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN regions ON users.ccounty = regions.county
    ) r ON u.users_id = r.users_id
```